# Is using free product key or license key safe

Tags: software, license-enforcement

I have installed VMWare Workstation Pro from the official website. Now after the trial version has ended, I have searched for free products key on the internet. If I use these product keys, will it be harmful to my PC? Will it install malware or backdoors?

Comment: You are basically asking if bypassing the license restrictions of a software for your own gain can be harmful. In short, in theory it can but if it does in practice depends on the reaction of the vendor and also the way the license was installed. Additionally you might face legal consequences, which might be even worse than malware. Anyway, this site does not encourage or support in any way bypassing security or license restrictions, so this question is mostly off-topic here.

Comment: Keys are just strings of letters and numbers. If you need to run anything that came with the key, then you can almost be certain that that thing is malware.